# Unable to find certain data(json objects) in json response with JProperty

Tags: c#, json, loops, object

I'm trying to debug my JProperty object but somehow I can not get all the data out of this object. When I debug te JProperty it says it has the data im trying to recieve but I'm only able to obtain a part of it, explanation:

So my response JSON looks like this:

```
{"url":"www.microsoft0nline.nl\/test.php","time":"2019-06-19 09:50:49","stringvalue":"otherValue1","intvalue":433,"array":["35","37","43"],"otherObject1":{"name":"object1","description":"A object type","size":120}}
```

I'm iterating through this with the following code:

```
foreach (JProperty property in jsonResponse.Properties())
{
}
```

So when I run my code in debug mode and i debug these properties I'm getting the following:

[image]

As you all can see the parent of *property* has the object "**otherObject1**" within.

Now I iterate through this *property* with the following code:

```
foreach (var itemsOfResponse in property)
{
   var dataJson = itemsOfResponse;                        
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dataJson);
}
```

And the response in my debugger looks like this:

```
www.microsoft0nline.nl/test.php
2019-06-19 10:01:49
otherValue1
433
[
  "35",
  "37",
  "43"
]
```

The response contains all the values of my json response exept the one of "otherObject1", how is this possible? And is there a way to obtain the key values(url, stringvalue, intvalue, etc) of these properties to?

Hope someone can help me out here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JProperty` is only a single name value token pair.

`JObject` will contain many `JToken` objects (including `JProperty` and `JObject` instances).

For what you are trying to do, you should probably use `JToken` as both `JProperty` and `JObject` are `JToken` derived classes.